# Flex listen to Operating system events when not in focus

Tags: apache-flex, air

Is there a way that a flex based application (in the browser or AIR) can listen to windows events (or any other OS) when it is not in focus?

Lets say that my AIR application is minimized and I want her to be notified when ever new data was copied to the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

No way, otherwise every ad in your browser would be potential keylogger. Not even AIR app can do that out the box. If your AIR app is native, it can run processes - so you could run helper application to watch OS events.